# Difference betweeng using Request and specific parameter names in Django

Tags: python, django, request, django-views, http-request

What is the key difference between view methods with just the `request` keyword or specifying exact parameter names?

For example, I see in code that there is view like this:

```
def get_accounts(request):
   in name in request.GET and request.GET['name']
```

And the other variant:

```
def get_accounts(request, name, some_custom_parameters):
   if name and some_custom_validations:
      some_expressions
```

My question regards the difference in usage. If I get a POST request from the front-end via jQuery or anything else; when (and why) do I have to use just the `request` keyword alone and when to specify concrete parameters as `request` can include all desired parameters within itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra arguments to your function are taken from your *path configuration*.

You set URL patterns; if you include elements in the URL pattern those will be passed on to your view as extra arguments:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/(?P<name>\w+)/(?P<some_custom_element>\w+)$', views. get_accounts),
    # ...
)
```

In the above example the view is configured to listen to any URL starting with `accounts/` and including two more elements; those are passed to your view as arguments.

In other words, it is *not* POST or GET request data that is being passed in to those arguments.

You probably want to [re-read the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/tutorial03/) on this subject.

You'd use extra parameters in your path to create friendly, bookmarkable URLs. The path `/users/1553537/giorgi-tsiklauri` is a lot more readable and friendly than `/users?id=1553537`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: it allows you to control what URLs work and what URLs are invalid.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: `request.GET` doesn't contain path elements. If your URL is `/users/1553537/giorgi-tsiklauri`, there is no `request.GET['id']` because there is no such GET parameter.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: there is *always* a request method, but the `requests.POST` is only populated if it was indeed the request used the `POST` method. `GET` is always available (URLs can always have parameters). For other request methods such as PUT and DELETE, you can always still access `request.body` for the raw request body data.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: there is also *always* a URL path (it can be `/` or longer) so there is *always* a `request` and if a view exists for that path then it'll be called.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL):

> Semantic URLs, also sometimes referred to as clean URLs, RESTful URLs, user-friendly URLs, or SEO-friendly URLs, are Uniform Resource Locators (URLs) intended to improve the usability and accessibility of a website or web service by being immediately and intuitively meaningful to non-expert users